# Discord.py: I get an AttributeError when I try to make my bot give roles on command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, attributeerror

How do I make my bot give roles through a command?
Nobody else asked this question and nobody else had an answer, I searched for more than an hour.
What I want is the user to say "give me member" and then the bot gives the member role.
This is the code:

```
import discord
import os
import random

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print ('logged in')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content == 'give me member':
        role = discord.utils.get(message.author.server.roles, id="863082485851750431")
        await bot.add_roles(message.author, role)
client.run('EnterToken')
```

I get this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Dbot2.py", line 19, in on_message
    role = discord.utils.get(message.author.server.roles, id="863082485851750431")
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'server'
```

Once you have an answer please give me code I can copy and paste (don't include the token)

Answer (score 1):

`server` is an old method and no longer supported, and `bot.add_roles` does not right since `bot` is not even defined and it is old It should be like this.

You should always check the date of the code you are taking

```py
role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=863082485851750431)
await message.author.add_roles(role)
```

Docs:

- [`Guild.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild%20roles#discord.Guild.roles)
- [`Message.guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message.guild)

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: The ID should be an `int` i have changed that above